# How to remove the background of a dialog?

Tags: gluon-mobile

I created a custom dialog with my own panes and controls in it. But the dialog has a white border default which I want to remove. Here is an example with a single image:

[image]

[image]

I tried using ScenicView but couldn't find a way to catch the dialog layer and modify it:

```
public class MainView extends View {

    Image img = new Image("https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg", 300, 500, true, true);

    public MainView(String name) {
        super(name);

        Button b = new Button("Pop");
        b.setOnAction(e -> {
            Dialog<Void> dialog = new Dialog<>();
            dialog.setOnShown(e2 -> {
                Parent parent = getParent();
                Pane p = (Pane) parent.lookup(".dialog");
                p.setPadding(new Insets(0));
            });
            dialog.setGraphic(new ImageView(img));
            dialog.showAndWait();
        });
        setCenter(b);
    }
}
```

Best i got was removing the flowpane child to remove some of the lower part

```
dialog.setOnShown(e2 -> {
    Parent parent = getParent();
    Pane p = (Pane) parent.lookup(".dialog");
    p.getChildren().removeIf(c -> (c instanceof FlowPane));
    System.out.println(p.getChildren());
});
```

Removing the VBox moves the dialog which i don't want to do and changing its padding also dose nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see with ScenicView, the `Dialog` has the `dialog` style class.

One easy way to modify the dialog style is via css. Just add a css file to your view, and set:

```
.dialog {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

That will set the background transparent, instead of the default white color.

If you want to remove the borders instead, then you can play with padding. As you can also see with ScenicView, the dialog has a VBox with style class `container` for the content in the center, and the flow pane for the buttons at the bottom, with style class `dialog-button-bar`.

Before anything, just use the `setContent` method to add the image instead of the `setGraphic` one:

```
dialog.setContent(new ImageView(img));
```

And this will be required to remove all the borders, and let the image take the whole dialog:

```
.dialog,
.dialog > .container,
.dialog > .dialog-button-bar {
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: So there's no way to do it programatically like i tried?

Comment: I don't see a problem using css? When you do it programmatically, the problem is the Gluon default css applied over the dialog, so the padding will be set regardless your attempt.